# couldn't start diff drive controller: Could not find resource 'Joint1'

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-controllers, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while launching diff drive controller i'm getting this kind of erros:

```
[ INFO] [1589084721.702629598]: Allow mutiple cmd_vel publishers is enabled
[ INFO] [1589084721.704429523]: Base frame_id set to base_footprint
[ INFO] [1589084721.705299981]: Odometry frame_id set to odom
[ INFO] [1589084721.706741402]: Publishing to tf is enabled
[ INFO] [1589084721.722586910]: Odometry params : wheel separation 1, left wheel radius 0.3, right wheel radius 0.3
[ INFO] [1589084721.725901716]: Adding left wheel with joint name: Joint1 and right wheel with joint name: Joint2
[ERROR] [1589084721.726199477]: Exception thrown while initializing controller 'mobile_base_controller'.
Could not find resource 'Joint1' in 'hardware_interface::VelocityJointInterface'.
[ERROR] [1589084721.726287254]: Initializing controller 'mobile_base_controller' failed
Error when loading 'mobile_base_controller'
Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully
[ERROR] [1589084721.743018591]: Could not start controller with name 'mobile_base_controller' because no controller with this name exists
```

launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- GDB functionality -->
  <arg name="debug" default="false" />
  <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="" />
  <arg     if="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="gdb --ex run --args" />

  <!-- Load example URDF -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find rrbot_description)/urdf/rrbot.xacro'" />

  <group ns="rrbot">

    <!-- Load hardware interface -->
    <node name="rrbot_hardware_interface" pkg="ros_control_boilerplate" type="sim_hw_main"
          output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)"/>

    <!-- Load controller settings -->
    <rosparam file="$(find ros_control_boilerplate)/rrbot_control/config/rrbot_controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

    <!-- Load controller manager -->
    <node name="ros_control_controller_manager" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" respawn="false"
      output="screen" args="spawn joint_state_controller mobile_base_controller" />

    <!-- Convert joint states to /tf tranforms -->
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>

  </group>

</launch>
```

config file:

```
# ros_control_boilerplate Settings -----------------------
# Settings for ros_control control loop
generic_hw_control_loop:
  loop_hz: 300
  cycle_time_error_threshold: 0.01

# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
   joints:
      - joint1
      - joint2
   sim_control_mode: 0 # 0: position, 1: velocity

# Publish all joint states ----------------------------------
# Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
joint_state_controller:
   type:         joint_state_controller/JointStateController
   publish_rate: 50

# Joint Trajectory Controller -------------------------------
# For detailed explanations of parameter see http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller
position_trajectory_controller:
   type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
   # These joints can likely just be copied from the hardware_interface list above
   joints:
      - joint1
      - joint2
   constraints:
      goal_time: 5.0
      #stopped_position_tolerance: 0.4 # Defaults to 0.01
      joint1:
          trajectory: 0.60
          goal:       0.15
      joint2:
          trajectory: 0.60
          goal:       0.15
   # gains:
   #     joint1: {p: 2.0,  i: 0.0, d: 0.01, i_clamp: 1}
   #     joint2: {p: 2.0,  i: 0.0, d: 0.01, i_clamp: 1}

    # state_publish_rate:  50 # Defaults to 50
    # action_monitor_rate: 20 # Defaults to 20
    #hold_trajectory_duration: 0 # Defaults to 0.5

mobile_base_controller:
  type        : "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  left_wheel  : 'Joint1'
  right_wheel : 'Joint2'
  publish_rate: 50.0               # default: 50
  pose_covariance_diagonal : [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]
  twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]

  # Wheel separation and diameter. These are both optional.
  # diff_drive_controller will attempt to read either one or both from the
  # URDF if not specified as a parameter
  wheel_separation : 1.0
  wheel_radius : 0.3

  # Wheel separation and radius multipliers
  wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0 # default: 1.0
  wheel_radius_multiplier    : 1.0 # default: 1.0

  # Velocity commands timeout [s], default 0.5
  cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25

  # Base frame_id
  base_frame_id: base_footprint #default: base_link

  # Velocity and acceleration limits
  # Whenever a min_* is unspecified, default to -max_*
  linear:
    x:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 1.0  # m/s
      min_velocity           : -0.5 # m/s
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 0.8  # m/s^2
      min_acceleration       : -0.4 # m/s^2
      has_jerk_limits        : true
      max_jerk               : 5.0  # m/s^3
  angular:
    z:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 1.7  # rad/s
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 1.5  # rad/s^2
      has_jerk_limits        : true
      max_jerk               : 2.5  # rad/s^3

# Individual Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
# Allows to send individual ROS msg of Float64 to each joint separately
joint1_position_controller:
   type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
   joint: joint1
   pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
joint2_position_controller:
   type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
   joint: joint2
   pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}

# Group Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
# Allows to send single ROS msg of Float64MultiArray to all joints
joint_position_controller:
   type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
   joints:
     - joint1
     - joint2
```

when i load another controllers described inside this config file like position trajectory controller, it works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351920/couldn%27t-start-diff-drive-controller:-could-not-find-resource-%27joint1%27/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2020-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is this:

> ```
> [ERROR] [1589084721.726199477]: Exception thrown while initializing controller 'mobile_base_controller'.
> ```

Could not find resource 'Joint1' in 'hardware_interface::VelocityJointInterface'.

Note how it says: cannot find `Joint1`.

Your config file contains this (I've removed irrelevant lines):

> ```
> hardware_interface:
>    joints:
>       - joint1
>       - joint2
>
> [..]
>
> position_trajectory_controller:
>    joints:
>       - joint1
>       - joint2
>
> [..]
>
> joint1_position_controller:
>    joint: joint1
> joint2_position_controller:
>    joint: joint2
>
> [..]
>
> joint_position_controller:
>    joints:
>      - joint1
>      - joint2
> ```

but then suddenly:

> ```
> mobile_base_controller:
>   left_wheel  : 'Joint1'
>   right_wheel : 'Joint2'
> ```

It's likely the joints are actually called `joint1` and `joint2`, not `Joint1` and `Joint2` (note the uppercase `J`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1